# Guice , unable to create injector

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, guice

Im trying to create in injector for testing an api.

```
The test binding are as follows
  class ApiTestModule extends AbstractModule {
    def configure(): Unit = {
      bind(classOf[Client]).in(classOf[Singleton])
      bind(classOf[ApiGetController]).in(classOf[Singleton])
      bind(classOf[ApiPostController]).in(classOf[Singleton])
      bind(classOf[IndexService]).in(classOf[Singleton])
      bind(classOf[PanelService]).in(classOf[Singleton])
      bind(classOf[EntitiesService]).in(classOf[Singleton])
      bind(classOf[AuthenticatedPublicApiAction]).in(classOf[Singleton])
      bind(classOf[RateLimitedApiAction]).in(classOf[Singleton])
      bind(classOf[ApiKeyValidatorUpdaterThread]).in(classOf[Singleton])
      bind(classOf[ApiKeyValidatorService]).in(classOf[Singleton])
      bind(classOf[ArticleFrontService]).in(classOf[Singleton])

    }
```

I've created te injector in the code

```
 val testModule = new AbstractModule() {
    def configure() = {
      new ApiTestModule().configure(binder())
    }
  }
  val injector = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .overrides(testModule).injector()

  val apiGetController = injector.instanceOf(classOf[ApiGetController])
```

And I'm getting the following error

exception or error caused a run to abort: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

```
1) No implementation for org.elasticsearch.client.Client annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=SpikeClient) was bound.
  while locating org.elasticsearch.client.Client annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=SpikeClient)
    for parameter 2 at com.newswhip.api.service.ApiArticleService.<init>(ApiArticleService.scala:19)
  while locating com.newswhip.api.service.ApiArticleService
    for parameter 1 at com.newswhip.api.controllers.ApiGetController.<init>(ApiGetController.scala:57)
  at com.newswhip.spike.inject.TestBindings$ApiTestModule.configure(TestBindings.scala:133) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> com.newswhip.api.service.ApiArticleServiceTest$$anon$1)

2) No implementation for org.elasticsearch.client.Client annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=SpikeClient) was bound.
  while locating org.elasticsearch.client.Client annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=SpikeClient)
    for parameter 2 at com.newswhip.api.service.ApiArticleService.<init>(ApiArticleService.scala:19)
  while locating com.newswhip.api.service.ApiArticleService
    for parameter 1 at com.newswhip.api.controllers.ApiPostController.<init>(ApiPostController.scala:17)
  at com.newswhip.spike.inject.TestBindings$ApiTestModule.configure(TestBindings.scala:134) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> com.newswhip.api.service.ApiArticleServiceTest$$anon$1)

3) No implementation for org.elasticsearch.client.Client annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=SpikeClient) was bound.
  while locating org.elasticsearch.client.Client annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=SpikeClient)
    for parameter 0 at com.newswhip.spike.article.service.SpikeEsQueryBuilder.<init>(SpikeEsQueryBuilder.scala:20)
  while locating com.newswhip.spike.article.service.SpikeEsQueryBuilder
    for parameter 2 at com.newswhip.spike.article.service.EntitiesService.<init>(EntitiesService.scala:30)
  at com.newswhip.spike.inject.TestBindings$ApiTestModule.configure(TestBindings.scala:137) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> com.newswhip.api.service.ApiArticleServiceTest$$anon$1)

4) No implementation for org.elasticsearch.client.Client was bound.
  at com.newswhip.spike.inject.TestBindings$ApiTestModule.configure(TestBindings.scala:131) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> com.newswhip.api.service.ApiArticleServiceTest$$anon$1)

5) No implementation for play.api.db.Database was bound.
  at com.newswhip.spike.inject.TestBindings$ApiTestModule.configure(TestBindings.scala:132) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> com.newswhip.api.service.ApiArticleServiceTest$$anon$1
```

)

I think the issue is in my my bindings module but I cant figure out what the issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mockito is useful for testing. I think you can try like below injection for testing with guice

```
class TestModule extends AbstractModule with MockitoSugar {

  val mockClient: Client = mock[Client]

  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bind(classOf[Client]).toInstance(mockClient)
  }

}
```

It is easy for mocking and stubbing. If you want mock or stub in test you can use like this

```
doReturn("dummyResult").when(testModule.mockClient).someMethod()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Guice's BoundFields](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BoundFields). Then you can create a test like this:

```
public class TestFoo extends WordSpec with BeforeAndAfterEach with MockitoSugar {
  // bind(Bar.class).toInstance(barMock);
  @Bind var barMock: Bar = _

  // Foo depends on Bar.
  @Inject var foo: Foo = _

  override def beforeEach() = {
    barMock = mock[Bar];
    Guice.createInjector(BoundFieldModule.of(this)).injectMembers(this);
  }

  "your Test" should {
    "do" in {
      // your test case
    }
  }
}
```